# Add user to Organic group after commerce product order with rules

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, organic-groups

I would appreciate any help, I have been searching for a solution for over a week now.

I have tried this tutorial https://drupalcommerce.org/blog/10809/selling-organic-groups-using-drupal-commerce but unfortunately the first component can't be completed because of an error message of data type not matching. Several people have complained about this but I'm yet to find a solution.

I also tried http://s1l.org/selling-access-organic-groups-drupal-commerce but the loop in the component doesn't give me the field that is in the tutorial.

I have also tried the [Commerce License](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license) module with the [Commerce License OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license_og) module. It expects the group to exist before the product is created. You are to select the group from a list of groups when creating the product. This doesn't match my use case. My groups are created after a product has been created.

Comment: I think you will need to explain a bit more detail on your use-case and your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this finally by tweaking the tutorial posted on this site: http://s1l.org/selling-access-organic-groups-drupal-commerce. I removed the loop in the components since my field only takes one value and I removed the condition to check if the order has been paid and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're struggling because your use case is very specific. I would start by creating Rules components to do just one thing as you can call Rules components as actions in other Rules, etc.

First start by creating a Rules component that assigns the user to the group and work backwards from there.